# Geometry Node: Simplest way to restrict value of a field

Tags: geometry-nodes

Let's say, in geometry nodes I have a vector field that is obtained from `Color` output of the `Noise Texture`. Now I want to restrict its x, y, z values to make them lie only within the range of 0 and 1. I can, of course, use the `Map Range` node, but it requires the input value range, and for this I will have to use something like `Attribute Statistic` to get get min and max of each of the x, y, z values of the vector. I want to avoid it if possible.

So, what is the simplest way I can restrict the value of a field to make it lie within a range (like 0 to 1) regardless of the input value range?

Edit: As pointed out by @Nathan in the comment, noise output is already within the range of 0-1. So the example in my original question should be changed to anything other than 0-1, let's say 0-0.5. My question is given any arbitrary input range, can we restrict the output to a fixed range without requiring the minimum and maximum values of the input range?

Comment: Are you looking for math/minimum and math/maximum?  Simple ways to clamp anything, including an attribute.  Or you are looking to normalize the ouput around all *possible* values?  Not doable in GN-- requires image processing techniques, and may only be valid for certain domains and sampling rates.  Note that noise texture output lies within 0,1 anyways.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks, I have edited the question to change the example range for noise texture. I am not sure if math/min would help in this case. Please have a look at the edit.

Comment: Are you aware of the clamp node ? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/clamp.html Separate XYZ > 3*Clamp > Combine XYZ

Comment: @Gorgious Could you post your reply as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: Sorry don't have the time right now. But You can answer your own question with your solution. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Gorgious](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86891/gorgious) correctly pointed out in the [comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282990/geometry-node-simplest-way-to-restrict-value-of-a-field#comment486331_282990), you can solve this by splitting the vector into its components and using the `Clamp` node for each float value:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the vector nodes `Minimum` and `Maximum` directly:

[image]

By the way: The node `Noise Texture` should actually always return a value between $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$, and therefore this should not be necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [@quellenform's versions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283176/35559), because they're more explicit, and readable, but I don't see your problem with using the clamped output of *Map Range*. So long as the input range is the same as the clamped output range, and  the interpolation is 'Linear', you wouldn't need any further information from *Attribute Statistic* ?

[image]

I don't need to know anything about this Suzanne, to keep her within the unit cube:

[image]